# Print every value within range iterator generator function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, generator, es6-generator

Iterator should print every value within range but its only printing alternate nos.

```js
function iterator(rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
  if (rangeStart == 0 && rangeEnd == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  var iterate = function*(start = 0, end = 5, step = 1) {
    let iterationcount = 0;
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
      yield i;
      iterationCount = i;
    }
    return iterationCount;
  }

  var values = iterate(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
  var tmp = [];


  while (values.next().value != undefined) {
    tmp.push(values.next().value);
  }
  return tmp.join(",");

}

console.log(iterator(0, 10))
```

expected

`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Result

`[1,3,5,7,9,10]`

Comment: You're calling `values.next()` _twice_ per loop... That's why you're skipping values.

Answer (score 4):

Every call to `next` will consume a value from the iterator, so the `while` condition is consuming a value that will therefore not get into `tmp`.

But... JavaScript allows you to consume values in much easier ways. For instance with `Array.from` or spread syntax you can collect all values from the iterator into an array.

Not your question, but:

- `iterationCount` serves no purpose in your code, so just drop that part.
- Why would the function behave differently when both range start and end are 0 than when start and end are both 10? I would remove that case. When the range end would be **less** than the start, it would make sense to exit, but that will happen anyway without any `if` statement.
- The name `iterator` for your function is somewhat misleading, as the return value is not an iterator, but a comma separated string. I would therefore call it `rangeToCsv`

```js
function rangeToCsv(rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
  var iterate = function*(start = 0, end = 5, step = 1) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
      yield i;
    }
  }

  var values = iterate(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
  
  return Array.from(values).join(",");
}

console.log(rangeToCsv(0, 10))
```